# Google firebase realtime database - how to get event updates on only a section of json tree

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

So imagine i have a firebase json tree that more or less looks like this:

```
 //ignore poorly nested structure as this is an example
{
"chats": {
"one": {
 "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
 "messages": {
   "m1": { "sender": "ghopper", "message": "Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth." },
   "m2": { ... },
   // a very long list of messages
 }
},
"two": { ... }
}
}
```

Now in firebase after i get a instance of the database how can i receive updates only when section "two" is altered. So i'd like to sync on section "two" and ignore changes to "one".

Firebase has a ValueEventListener class that i can use which looks like this:

```
 ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chats.class);
 // ...this gets me the entire Chats object, i just needs the "two" object
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
```

so im having trouble with how i can subscribe to changes to only the "two" event.  I do not know how to set the event listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attach a listener to the node you want to listen to:

```
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference sectionTwo = root.child("two");
sectionTwo.addValueListener(...
```

You can easily see how the sample snippets from our documentation work by clicking the link at the bottom of them. For the snippet you copied from the section on [listening for value events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) that link leads to [this file in Github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/database/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/database/PostDetailActivity.java#L84-L106).